# Does lookbehind work in sed?

Tags: regex, sed, grep, lookbehind

I created a test using `grep` but it does not work in `sed`.

```
grep -P '(?<=foo)bar' file.txt
```

This works correctly by returning `bar`.

```
sed 's/(?<=foo)bar/test/g' file.txt
```

I was expecting `footest` as output, but it did not work.

Comment: sed does not support lookaround assertions.

Comment: For what it's worth, `grep -P` is also a nonstandard extension, though typically available on Linux (but not other platforms).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

GNU sed does not have support for lookaround assertions. You could use a more powerful language such as Perl or possibly experiment with [`ssed`](https://launchpad.net/ssed/) which supports Perl-style regular expressions.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=foo)bar/test/g' file.txt
```

Comment: The text accompanying your solution doesn't quite make sense since Perl doesn't support PCRE either (at least not natively).

Answer (score 48):

Note that most of the time you can avoid a lookbehind (or a lookahead) using a capture group and a backreference in the replacement string:

```
sed 's/\(foo\)bar/\1test/g' file.txt
```

---

Simulating a negative lookbehind is more subtile and needs several substitutions to protect the substring you want to avoid. Example for `(?<!foo)bar`:

```
sed 's/#/##/g;s/foobar/foob#ar/g;s/bar/test/g;s/foob#ar/foobar/g;s/##/#/g' file.txt
```

- choose an escape character and repeat it (for example `#` => `##`).
- include this character in the substring you want to protect (`foobar` here, => `foob#ar` or `ba` => `b#a`).
- make your replacement.
- replace `foob#ar` with `foobar` (or `b#a` with `ba`).
- replace `##` with `#`.

---

Obviously, you can also describe all that isn't `foo` before `bar` in a capture group:

```
sed -E 's/(^.{0,2}|[^f]..|[^o].?)bar/\1test/g' file.txt
```

But it will quickly become tedious with more characters.

Comment: But this does not work for "negative" lookbehind, e.g. you want "bar" NOT preceded by "foo" to be replaced with "test", what would be done (if it worked) with  /(?<!foo)bar/test/. Has anyone a solution to this? (I want to use uniq on the 5th field of an SQL file but preceding fields may contain spaces so I have no better idea than to replace all spaces NOT between ...', '... by "_"...)

Comment: @Max: 1) choose an escape character and repeat it (for example `#` => `##`). 2) include this character in the substring you want to protect (`foobar` here, => `foob#ar`). 3) make your replacement. 4) replace `foob#ar` with `foobar`. 5) replace `##` with `#`. Example with sed: `sed 's/#/##/g;s/foobar/foob#ar/g;s/bar/test/g;s/foob#ar/foobar/g;s/##/#/g' <<<'abc foobar # foob#ar foo bar'`

Comment: OK, yes that works, essentially you *remove* what you want to protect (maybe `foobar`=>`-#-` (instead foob#ar) would be clearer), then you find & replace all others, then you put the "protected" ones back

Comment: @Max: `foobar` => `-#-`: if you want (and only if you have replaced all `#` with `##` before).

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Thanks Chirico (and the sorceress) for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

sed doesn't support lookarounds but [choose](https://github.com/jagprog5/choose) (I'm the author) does. It uses PCRE2 syntax.

For example:

```bash
$ echo "hello bar foobar" | choose -r --sed '(?<=foo)bar' --replace test
hello bar footest
```

It's speed is [comparable](https://github.com/jagprog5/choose/blob/main/perf/perf.md#stream-editing) to sed.