# What characters do I need to escape with sed to make this regex work

Tags: regex, linux, sed, ip

```
(?<![0-9])0+(?=[0-9]+)
```

I need to remove unnecessary leading zeros in malformed octettes of IP addresses.

I want to do something like this but it is not working.

```
cat Qualys-Active-IPs.csv | awk -F';' {'print $1'} | sed 's/(?<![0-9])0+(?\=[0-9]+)//g'
```

Comment: Escaping won't help, lookarounds are not supported with `sed`.

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/([^0-9]|^)0+([^0-9]|$)/\1\2/g'` or `perl -pe 's/(?<![0-9])0+(?=[0-9])//g'`

Comment: Is there a CLI tool that I could use as an alternative or another combination of piping commands?

Comment: Unfortunately you suggesstion did not work, but this did: sed -r 's/^0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)$/\1.\2.\3.\4/'

Comment: [`sed -r 's/([^0-9]|^)0+([0-9])/\1\2/g'` would work, but the `perl` solution was already correct.](http://rextester.com/NIOE62860)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does lookbehind work in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110266/does-lookbehind-work-in-sed)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
 sed -r 's/^0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)$/\1.\2.\3.\4/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code:

```
sed -r 's/^0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)-0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+)\.0*([0-9]+),...,(.*)$/\9:\1.\2.\3.\4-\5.\6.\7.\8/'
```