# Sed substitution with negative lookahead and negative lookbehind regex

Tags: sed

I have to replace all the numbers in the ranges **35-79** and **235-249** with a text, let's say "hello world".

After a few minutes I came up with this expression:

```
sed -r "s/((3[5-9]|[4-7][0-9])|(23[5-9]|24[0-9]))/[\1 hello world]/g" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

The problem I had is that it also identified parts of larger numbers as valid numbers. For example, in the number 256, 56 was detected as a valid input, and that's not what I wanted. These numbers are preceded and followed by white spaces or random alphanumeric characters, so using the word boundary would not be an option. I managed to solve that using negative lookbehind and negative lookahead, obtaining this result:

```
sed -r "s/(((?<![0-9])3[5-9](?![0-9])|(?<![0-9])[4-7][0-9](?![0-9]))|(23[5-9]|24[0-9]))/[\1 hello world]/g" file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Unfortunately, sed doesn't recognize lookbehind and lookahead. I know Perl does, but I'm forced to do this using only sed. Any idea about how to solve this in sed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110266/does-lookbehind-work-in-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`

```sh
$ echo '40-840-236;59a' | perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)(23[5-9]|24\d|3[5-9]|[4-7]\d)(?!\d)/[$1 hello world]/g'
[40 hello world]-840-[236 hello world];[59 hello world]a
```

With `sed` (syntax checked with `GNU sed`, will differ for other implementations)

```sh
$ echo '40-840-236;59a' | sed -E ':a s/(^|[^0-9])(3[5-9]|[4-7][0-9]|23[5-9]|24[0-9])([^0-9\n]|$)/\1[\2\n hello world]\3/; ta; s/\n//g'
[40 hello world]-840-[236 hello world];[59 hello world]a
```

- `:a` label `a`
- `(^|[^0-9])` match start of line or non-digit character
- `(3[5-9]|[4-7][0-9]|23[5-9]|24[0-9])` valid numbers to be matched
- `([^0-9\n]|$)` match non-digit, non-newline characters or end of line
- `\1[\2\n hello world]\3` all the capture groups, required output format, plus an additional `newline` character to avoid loop running forever
- `ta` branch to label `a` as long as the substitution succeeds
- `s/\n//g` remove the extra newlines